# unable to read row inserted in mysql database using php using a php function, just after the function is called

Tags: php, mysql

called a function like :-

```
$setmessage = setlatestmessage($sessionid, $sendersuserid, $message1);
```

the function is in file functions.php, which i had included in this file
The function is :-

```
function setlatestmessage($sessionid, $userid, $message, $status = 0) {
    $dbc = mysqli_connect(hostname, username, password, database)
            or die("Error connecting database");

    // there was no row, so just add a row
    $query2 = "insert into table(session_id, user_id, message, status) values ( $sessionid, $userid, '$message', $status)";
    mysqli_query($dbc, $query2);

    // if a row was affected, close connection and send true
    if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) == 1) {
        mysqli_close($dbc);
        return TRUE;
    }
    mysqli_close($dbc);
    return FALSE;
}
```

now, just after i had called this function, the script goes like

```
if (!$setmessage) {
                echo '<status>0</status>';
            } else {
                // fetch id of the row just inserted
                $query2 = "select id from game_messages where session_id = $sessionid and message = '$message1' and user_id = $sendersuserid order by datetime desc limit 1";
                $result2 = mysqli_query($dbc, $query2);

                if (mysqli_num_rows($result2) == 0) {
                    // if no row was returned
                    // case never should happen
                    echo '<status>10</status>';
                }
                else{echo'done';}
```

The output i get is 10.

However, if i just place a sleep(50) under the function call, or i just code what the function is doing, instead of the function call, i get correct output.
Cant figure out  why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be much easier and simpler if you would return the ID generated with your last insert query in `setlatestmessage()` function using `mysqli_insert_id()` or false on error. Then you would simply check:

```
$messageID = setlatestmessage($sessionid, $sendersuserid, $message1);

if ($messageID !== false)
{
    echo '<status>0</status>';
}
else
{
    echo '<status>10</status>';
}
```

Comment: Thanx man !! It worked like a charm. But it would be more helpful, if you could tell, why my code did not work ...

Comment: I don't know, haven't tested it